# Dynamic Binding is not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm a beginner in wpf. I am following a textbook to learn, the examples are shown but its not working whenever I am writing dynamic binding part even after following each of its instructions strictly thrice.
this is the code behind

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace KarliCards_GUI
{
    [Serializable]
    public class GameOptions:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _playAgainstComputer = false;
        public bool PlayAgainstComputer 
        { 
            get
            {
                return _playAgainstComputer;

            }
        set
        {
            _playAgainstComputer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PlayAgainstComputer");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

}

In XAML file I want to dynamically bind IsChecked property of a checkbox by using DataContext which will have an instance of GameOptions.
Below part of code is in XAML file

```
<CheckBox Content="Play against computer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="playAgainstComputerCheck" IsChecked="{Binding Path=PlayAgainstComputer}" />
```

and below is the code of csharp file of that XAML

```
namespace KarliCards_GUI
{
    public partial class Options : Window
    {
        private GameOptions _gameOptions;
        public Options()
        {
            if (_gameOptions == null)
            {
                if (File.Exists("GameOptions.xml"))
                {
                    using (var stream = File.OpenRead("GameOptions.xml"))
                    {
                        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GameOptions));
                        _gameOptions = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as GameOptions;
                    }
                }
                else
                    _gameOptions = new GameOptions();
            }
            DataContext = _gameOptions;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
   }
}
```

The problem I am facing is, in the property 'PlayAgainstComputer', in set part if I set the variable(_playAgainstComputer) as 'value' it is always checked in the checkbox.

Comment: Might be the case the since the `InitializeComponent()` method is being called after the `DataContext` is set. The default value for `IsChecked` property of `CheckBox` is `true`. I suggest first to call the `InitializeComponent()` method and then set the `DataContext`

Comment: Tip: us nameof(PlayAgainstComputer) instead of "PlayAgainstComputer" in             OnPropertyChanged("PlayAgainstComputer");, if you ever rename this, the string won't be renamed.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the case the since the `InitializeComponent()` method is being called after the `DataContext` is set.

The default value for `IsChecked` property of `CheckBox` is `true`. I suggest first to call the `InitializeComponent()` method and then set the DataContext.

Comment: Can you post the values after deserializing the xml?

Comment: Debug.WriteLine("BarunDEBUG_Result-> "+_gameOptions.PlayAgainstComputer);


it is showing **true** in Debug window

Comment: Put a break point on the line `_playAgainstComputer = value;` and then toggle the `CheckBox` on the UI. See if the `value` changes between `true`(checked) and `false`(unchecked). If that is working then I really don't see any problem.

Comment: at that point 
_playAgainstComputer=false and value=true 
which is later assigned in the variable to make that true. 

That is my question, who is setting the property is 'true' and how to avoid it to make the dynamic binding.